# Android app calls a number other than the one I've specified

Tags: android, android-intent

I have built an app which makes calls programmatically in Android, but the number I have put in the source code isn't being called. Rather, another number, `686237`, is always called, regardless of what I specify in the source code. I am using Windows 10 and developing on a Huawei P20 lite with Android Studio 3.5.

I've tried installing this app on another device, but it still calls the same, incorrect number. I have Googled the number to see if this is a common issue, but haven't found any helpful information.

So what is this number, and why is Android Studio 3.5 putting it in my app? What do I need to change in my code to make my app call the number that I specify?

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   String number = "tel: 002800002542";
   Intent appelIntent = new Intent(Intent.CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "number"));
   startActivity(appelIntent);
}}
```

Comment: thanks you for your reply but App launchs and stops immediately

Comment: Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=number }

Comment: All is all right I followed what you told me and add a try catch, thank's

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent appelIntent = new Intent(Intent.CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "number"));
```

You are passing the String values of the words `"number"` and `"tel:"`. To call your desired number, you need to reference the variable `number` instead.

Comment: All is all right I followed what you told me and add a try catch, thank's

Comment: Here is the final code : try {
            String number = "05502842";
            Intent my_callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            my_callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ number));
            startActivity(my_callIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error in your phone call"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String number = "002800002542";
    Intent appelIntent = new Intent(Intent.CALL); // or you can use Intent.ACTION_CALL, Intent.ACTION_DIAL
    appelIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
    startActivity(appelIntent);
}
```